# How to divide an object along irregular edges?

Tags: modifiers, objects

I'm trying to design a mold to print on a 3D printer. I've tried several ways including bisect but I think that my need is a little bit more complex. My first try was creating a cube, inside of it a sphere and then I applied a boolean modifier but I realized that it was difficult for me to divide the cube in 8 smaller cubes (because I need each piece to be unique like the image below). My second try was creating a cube, subdividing it and then applying the boolean operator to remove the sphere so that it was actually a mold but I couldnt find any way to separate the smaller cubes into different objects. My latest attempt was creating 8 smaller cubes and arranging them as a big cube and then applying the boolean operator to each one. That one is the closest I've been but now I want to make each piece fit in only one possible location by modifyng the edges. The object on the left (8 small cubes with the shape of a sphere inside) is what I have so far and I would like the pieces to look like the object on the right. [image: most recent progress]